# Picture of Cards not showing on Java BlackJack Game

Tags: java, oop, object, graphics

I cannot get the picture of cards to show up. It is only the image that is not showing up. Everything else is correct.
Here are all the relevant files. 
Abstract Player

```
public abstract class AbstractPlayer implements Playerable {

private ArrayList<Card> hand;
private int winCount;


    public AbstractPlayer()
    {
        hand = new ArrayList<Card>();
        winCount = 0;
    }

    public AbstractPlayer(int score) 
    {
        winCount = score;
    }

    public void addCardToHand(Card temp)
    {
       hand.add(temp);
    }

    public void resetHand() {
        hand.clear();
    }

    public void setWinCount(int numwins)
    {
        winCount = numwins;
    }

    public int getWinCount()
    {
        return winCount;
    }

    public int getHandSize() 
    {
        return hand.size();
    }

    public ArrayList<Card> getHand()
    {
        return hand;
    }

    public int getHandValue() 
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(Card c: hand)
            sum = sum + c.getValue();
        return sum;
    }

    public String toString() 
    {
        return "hand = " + hand.toString() + " \n-  # wins " + winCount;
    }

    public void drawHand(Graphics window, int x, int y)
    {
       window.create(x, y, 90, 120);
    }
   }
```

Player
                public class Player extends AbstractPlayer
         {
            //constructors
        public Player()
        {
            super();
        }

```
    public Player(int score)
    {
        super(score);
    }

    public boolean hit() 
    {
        //no code needed with GUI version
        return false;
    }
    }
```

PlayerTestTwo

```
    public class PlayerTestTwo extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

    private Deck deck;
    private Player player;
    private Font font;
    private boolean start;
    private boolean hit;
    private boolean finish;
    private boolean show;

    public PlayerTestTwo() {
        setBackground(new Color(34, 139, 34));

        deck = new Deck();
        player = new Player();

        font = new Font("TAHOMA", Font.BOLD, 12);

        this.addKeyListener(this);    //starts the key thread running
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics window) {
        super.paintComponent(window);

        window.setColor(Color.black);
        window.setFont(font);
        window.drawString("BlackJack Player Test", 25, 50);
        window.drawString("PRESS B to add cards to your hand.", 25, 100);

        if (start == true) {
            deck.shuffle();
            player.addCardToHand(deck.nextCard());
            player.addCardToHand(deck.nextCard());
            start = false;
            show = false;
        }

        window.drawString("PLAYER ", 50, 165);
        player.drawHand(window, 10, 185);
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyChar() == 'b' || e.getKeyChar() == 'B') {
            start = true;
            repaint();
        }
        if (Character.toLowerCase(e.getKeyChar()) == 'r'
                || Character.toLowerCase(e.getKeyChar()) == 'q') {
            deck = new Deck();
            player = new Player();
            repaint();

        }
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}


Test File
     import javax.swing.JFrame;
     import java.awt.Component;
     public class CardDeckPlayerGraphicsRunner extends JFrame {

    private static final int WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 600;

    public CardDeckPlayerGraphicsRunner() {
        super("BLACKJACK CardDeckPlayerRunner");
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        //test the Card class
        CardTestTwo cardTest = new CardTestTwo();
        getContentPane().add(cardTest);

        //test the Deck class
       DeckTestTwo deckTest = new DeckTestTwo();
      ((Component)deckTest).setFocusable(true);

       getContentPane().add(deckTest);
        //test the Player class
        PlayerTestTwo playerTest = new PlayerTestTwo();
       ((Component)playerTest).setFocusable(true);
        getContentPane().add(playerTest);
       setVisible(true);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        CardDeckPlayerGraphicsRunner run = new CardDeckPlayerGraphicsRunner();
    }
}
```

Comment: The question I have is, what do you think Graphics#create does?

Comment: Umm, draw a picture?

Comment: @MadProgrammer What is the proper method I should use?

Comment: No, create creates a sub set of graphics context translated so that 0x0 is the top/left corner, drawImage would draw an image, but I don't see any where you've loaded any

Comment: I highly recommend a visit to [Graphics2D trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/TOC.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Thanks for your advice!! It worked

Comment: And now you've learnt some new things :)